# How do I schedule only one vertex to the next round in a Blazegraph GAS Program?

Tags: graph-databases, blazegraph, bigdata

I'm implementing a GAS Program, but I have a doubt on how I can schedule only one vertex to the next round.

What I'm trying to do involves calculating the probability of going to the next vertex and going to the one with the highest probability. So, assuming I calculate the probability and update the probability value inside each VS,
in the Scatter phase, how can I check all possible next vertex values and schedule only the one with the highest value?

In other words, I need my frontier at `t + 1` to be only one vertex. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by scheduling all vertices in the Scatter phase, and then, in the `nextRound` method, iterating through the frontier and then selecting the vertex with (in my case) the highest probability. Then I reset the frontier setting only the selected vertex using the `resetFrontier` method.